# How can I access private value from object

Tags: yii2

I have the following object

```css
[yii\authclient\clients\Twitter_ef71f520786335688cd762d29aaa2ac98b6bd42f_token] => yii\authclient\OAuthToken Object
        (
            [tokenParamKey] => oauth_token
            [tokenSecretParamKey] => oauth_token_secret
            [createTimestamp] => 1447473086
            [_expireDurationParamKey:yii\authclient\OAuthToken:private] => 
            [_params:yii\authclient\OAuthToken:private] => Array
                (
                    [oauth_token] => 48575497-RTIItaMJBC5LrFl0I2TjYw0ihByC0QuRdRxf44tVX
                    [oauth_token_secret] => IcdvTgwiclWGNhX4TrsDjEkEdNwVF7l1XzXmgpNstGfkV
                    [user_id] => **********
                    [screen_name] => ***********
                    [x_auth_expires] => 0
                )

        )
```

and in the above object I want to access the parameter `oauth_token` and `oauth_token_secret` which are under `_params:yii\authclient\OAuthToken:private`

How do I get those values in php?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-authclient/blob/master/OAuthToken.php#L86

`yii\authclient\OAuthToken` has public method `getParams()` and `getParam($name)`